# Does Thrall ever explain things to Durotan or Draka?

Tags: warcraft

In the current WoW expansion, [Warlords of Draenor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Warcraft:_Warlords_of_Draenor), former Horde Warchief [**Thrall**](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Thrall) finds himself fighting alongside allies Durotan & Draka, the leaders of the Frostwolf Clan. As Thrall well knows, these two are

> his parents, neither of which he had a chance to know in the prime timeline.

I have gotten at least one Horde character to 100, but so far I haven't seen any questlines where this relationship is revealed to the characters in question.

**At any point in the expansion, does Thrall explain to Durotan & Draka who he is?**

Comment: it appears he doesn't, all i could find was a quote from blizzard saying they dont want to deal with time traveling shenanigans. Though i believe they shouldn't even have thrall for another 5-10 years, at least thats when it happened in the original timeline.

Comment: During the quest-line where you confront Garrosh, Aggra (Thrall's wife) tells Durotan that he is "like a father to Thrall". This leads me to believe that neither Durotan nor Draka are aware of the relationship.